# How to add values from JSON to a table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I following  [this](https://code-boxx.com/ajax-long-polling-php-mysql/) tutorial to create a real-time table with PHP and AJAX. The PHP file returns values in JSON format:

```
{ "retcode" : "0 Done", "trans_id" : "187472", "answer" : [ { "Country" : "US", "Digits" : "5", "Datetime" : "1586259875", "DatetimeMsc" : "1586259875596", "First" : "1.08580", "Second" : "1.08589" } , { "Country" : "China", "Digits" : "5", "Datetime" : "1586259877", "DatetimeMsc" : "1586259877000", "First" : "1.23311", "Second" : "1.23327"} , { "Country" : "Russia", "Digits" : "3", "Datetime" : "1586259874", "DatetimeMsc" : "1586259874585", "First" : "108.897", "Second" : "108.914" } ] }
```

My JS function to update the values in real-time is:

```
update : function (data) {
var message = "<p>Retcode: " + data['retcode'] + "</p>";
message += "<p>Trans ID: " + data['trans_id'] + "</p>";
message += "<p>UPDATED: " + data['answer'] + "</p>";
document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = message;
symbols.last = data['t'];
symbols.poll(); 
}
```

The PHP files code is:

```
while (true) {
$symbols=$request->Get('/symbol_last?country=US,China,Russia');
if($symbols!=false)
{
$newsymbols=json_encode($symbols);
echo $newsymbols;
return $newsymbols;
break;
}
sleep(1);
}
```

The HTML File include this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
  AJAX Long Polling Values
</title>
<script src="symbols.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="values"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The resulet of this is:

[image]

where Trans ID is real-time value and increases real-time by one. How to retrieve the other values of the answer (Country, First, Second) and show it in a table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

U need to convert your string to a JSON object

```
update : function (data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var message = "<p>Retcode: " + jsonData['retcode'] + "</p>";
    message += "<p>Trans ID: " + jsonData['trans_id'] + "</p>";
    message += "<p>UPDATED: " + jsonData['answer'] + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = message;
    symbols.last = data['t'];
    symbols.poll(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Kanayo. Thanks for your answer but if I convert to JSON object as you wrote then nothing is shown in the browser.

Comment: it should work fine, check to make sure that the PHP code returns a `json_encode($array)`

Comment: I changed. Then I have the same result with the IMG that I uploaded.

Comment: Ok. I did. With the above code, I have the same result.